# Install Docker on Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop

Tags: gui, docker

I'm totally new and want to learn how to handle apps with Docker. I installed Ubuntu 18.04, how can I get Docker up and running? Do I have to add something because I don't have Ubuntu server installed? Is there a GUI for Docker to make it easier to start?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to detail docker usage in a short answer, however there a nice guide on https://docs.docker.com/

First you install Docker engine: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ and than you can start configuring your own containers based on Debian, Ubuntu or any other supported system which is an art per se.

I would suggest that you first familiarize yourself with images with standard apps like apt-get, Firefox, LibreOffice and others, than start using Volumes and Bind mounts for data storage and finally start writing apps.

Docker website is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu desktop should be fine. I have yet to encounter any difference for my development purposes. For production, the Ubuntu server edition would be recommended not because of any difference in docker(I have yet to encounter one) but because of more sane defaults like not allowing password based ssh.

**Installation steps:**

1. verify that Docker isn't already installed by running:

   ```
   sudo docker -v
   ```

   If it's not installed, follow the instruction to install it from here:
   https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
2. You would probably like to use docker without prefixing sudo all the
   time. For that do:

   ```
   sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
   ```

   You can explore this and other such configurations like starting Docker on boot over here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/
3. As a new user you probably would also like to setup compose while
   you are at it. It's the most common way most applications are
   distributed in their docker form. The installation steps can be seen
   here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose-on-linux-systems

You could explore a GUI like portainer after you are familiar with the command line. It really wouldn't help in making it easy for you to learn docker in my opinion.